# Find first and last index of substring

Tags: javascript, string, function, console

How can I find out the start and end index of a substring within a string?

```js
let equation = "x^2 - 9";
console.log(equation.search(/x\^2/gi))
```

Answer (score 0):

never mind i was a bit confused and i forget the match method the answer is

```js
let equation = "x^2 - 9";
console.log(equation.match(/x\^2/gi).toString())
```